# Write the values of a customer group into a Series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` which has various entries of customers. These customers, which has different customer numbers, belong to certain customer groups (contract, wholesaler, tender, etc.). I have to sum some of these values of the `dataframe` into a `Series` for each customer group (e.g., total sales of contract customers would be a single entry in the `Series`.)

I've tried using `.isin()` but I had an attribute error (`float object has no attribute 'isin'`). It is working if I work with `or` operator but then I will have to manually enter all customer numbers for all customer groups. I'm sure there must be a much simple way and efficient of doing it. Many thanks in advance.

```py
    for i in range(len(grouped_sales)):
        if df.iloc[i,1]==value1 or df.iloc[i,1]==value2 or df.iloc[i,1]==...:
          series[1]=series[1]+df.iloc[i,3]

        elif df.iloc[1,i]==valueN or df.iloc[i,1]==value(N+1)...:
          series[2]=series[2]+df.iloc[1,3]
        elif:
           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the sales for every group you may want to look into panda's

`df.groupby()` maybe

I'm trying to reproduce what you want it would look like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['cust_numb']=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> df['group']=['group1','group2','group3','group3','group1']
>>> df['sales']=[50,30,50,40,20]

>>> df
   cust_numb   group  sales
0          1  group1     50
1          2  group2     30
2          3  group3     50
3          4  group3     40
4          5  group1     20

>>> df.groupby('group').sum()['sales']
group
group1    70
group2    30
group3    90
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

You'll have a series with groups as index and the sum of the sales as values

EDIT: Based on your comment you have the group data in a separate dictionary, the implementation would like this

```
>>> sales_data = {'CustomerName': ['cust1', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust4'],'CustomerCode': [1,2,3,4], 'Sales': [10,10,15,25], 'Risk':[55,55,45,79]}             
>>> sdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales_Data)
>>> group_data ={'group1': [1,3], 'group2': [2,4]}
```

You want to map your customer number to the groups so you need an inverted dictionary:

```
>>> dc = {v:k for k in group_data.keys() for v in group_data[k]}
{1: 'group1', 3: 'group1', 2: 'group2', 4: 'group2'}
```

You replace your customer number column by the group mapping in a new column and reproduce what I did above

```
>>> sdf['groups'] = sdf.replace({'CustomerCode': dc})['CustomerCode']
>>> sdf 
CustomerName  CustomerCode  Sales  Risk  groups
0        cust1             1     10    55  group1
1        cust2             2     10    55  group2
2        cust3             3     15    45  group1
3        cust4             4     25    79  group2
>>> sdf.groupby('groups').sum()['Sales']
groups
group1    25
group2    35
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I don't have the customer groups in the data unfortunately.What I need is exactly what groupby() does. `df.iloc[i,1]` in my code is the customer number. I need to match it with the set of customer numbers belonging to the group, which is a different dataframe in my environement.

Comment: Could you edit your question as to show me exactly what your dataframes look like? If I understand correctly, you have a mapping of customer number to group in a different dataframe and for some reasons you can't merge the dataframes together. You can iterate through the groups using your other dataframe, then use `df.loc` on your initial dataframe to use only the customers belonging to that group.

Comment: ```python
>>>sales_data = {'CustomerName': ['cust1', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust4'], 'CustomerCode': [Customer no.1, customer no.2, Customer no.3, Customer no.4], 'Sales': [10,10,15,25], 'Risk':[55,55,45,79]}

>>>pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales_data)

>>>group_data={'Group1': [Customer no.1, Customer no.2,...,Customer no.n], 'Group2': [Customer no.n,,...Customer no.q,], ..., 'GroupX': [...]}


>>>pd.DataFrame.from_dict(group_data)
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

Comment: I'm sorry about my inability to use the formatting properly.

Comment: @bahcecib I edited the answer based on your environment.

Comment: @bahcecib if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @HerpDerp Your approach to my problem was spot on. Unfortunately, I can't create an inverted dictionnary. I used your method and some others too. I always get `Series/List object is mutable, it cannot be hashed`  error.